# Lightning: How to use Custom Labels inside components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, localization

What is the way to use localized labels from Custom Labels or from field config inside lightning components?

In VF it was possible like:

- `$ObjectType[sObjectName].fields[fieldName].Type`
- `$Labels.Custom_Label`

Comment: Custom Labels are found, but what about Custom Object Labels -  $ObjectType??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This feature has now been added as of Summer '15

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_value_provider_platform.htm

Comment: Still not available for $ObjectType, though... best bet is going to be to retrieve it from an Apex controller method using DescribeSObjectResult or DescribeFieldResult

Comment: See official documentation here: [Using Custom Labels](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_value_provider_platform.htm)

Answer (score 3):

In Lightning Components, these are called global value providers. Currently there are only a few, including $Locale, and $Browser.

Some of the very useful global variables that exist in Visualforce such as the two you state and others like $User, $Profile, and others have not yet been implemented in Lightning Component Framework.

Comment: Hi Peter, is there a list of what is actually there and what is missing compared to Visualforce?

Comment: I've not seen a public doc.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement, what I did mayn't be the optimum solution; but it does suffice my requirement.

I had created a CustomLabel csv file and uploaded as a Static Resource.

Hope this will help you too.