# Are custom labels supported in Lightning Components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, customlabel, localization

For Visualforce we are using custom labels as described here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_label.htm

The usage is very simple:

```
{!$Label.yourLabelName}
```

Labels are a very important building brick if it comes to I18n/L10n and translations using Translation Workbench.

Are they supported in Lightning Components yet?

Comment: I believe this is answered here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70748/lightning-how-to-use-custom-labels-inside-components?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Use custom labels](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_value_provider_platform.htm) in Lightning components with the $Label global value provider.

Use this syntax to access custom labels in Lightning components:

**$Label.c.labelName** for the default namespace

**$Label.namespace.labelName** if your org has a namespace
    Here are some examples.

```
Label in a markup expression using the default namespace
{!$Label.c.labelName}

Label in JavaScript code if your org has a namespace

$A.get("$Label.namespace.labelName")
```